# Rewrite URLs: directories to file with underscore

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm really slow with .htaccess.

I just need to rewrite / to /content/index.php, and any other directory except 'content' and 'admin' like so:
/animals/ -> /content/animals.php
/animals/dogs/ -> /content/animals_dogs.php
/animals/dogs/pitbull/ -> /content/animals_dogs_pitbulls.php
etc.

How could I accomplish something like this?

Thanks a 1000 in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried Googling, but haven't found anything similar that I could hack, and I really have no idea where to start :-/

Comment: Well my humble suggestion is to start with simple rewrite schemes. What you're asking for others to do is definitely not a simple one.